# $route['viewproduct/(:any)']='Product/viewproduct/$1'; will change my default directory path

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

```
$route['viewproduct/(:any)']='Product/viewproduct/$1';
```

will change my default directory path. i set path into
 `https://baseurl/project/`

but after i call route path change to `https://baseurl/project/viewprodect` in all js &css href

Comment: Can you edit the question and explain more about your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue once, i had 2 scenarios:

### Scenario 1:

application/config/config.php

```
config['base_url'] = '';  
//this should be defined as the page location, on localhost it should be
//localhost/TheAppFolder, or http://this.is.my.page
```

if this is the case then the `base_url()` method takes what's writen on the browser url, it will try to take the css and js from

```
 http://this.is.my.page/something/MyCSSfile.css
 http://this.is.my.page/something/MyJSFile.js
```

this will happen if on ur views u call the css or js like this

```
<script src="../../MyJsfile.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../myCssFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**How to solve it?**

Let's say all ur css and js goes on a folder names **assets** on the public_html folder, so all routes to ur css and js files will be something like

```
../assets/js/myJsFile.js    //JS file
../assets/css/myCssFile.css //CSS file
```

on each of the `<link>` and `<script>` tags write them like this:

```
 <link href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/myCssFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

 <script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/MyJsfile.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
```

### Scenario 2:

/applicationFolder/.htaccess file

I found this issue many times, the solution is to simply change the .htaccess file content to

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

change the js & css path to

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```